# Styling off after JQuery Append

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, dom, browser

I have a weird problem that happens in all browsers except for Firefox. The Show More button losses its padding when I do an ajax request and append data to the table...

On first load (non-ajax) the button displays properly in all browsers. When I click the Show more button which sends a request to get more data (rows) back, the button losses it's bottom padding.

If I open up Chrome's or IE's development tool and click on the

or  tag element for the button it brings back the padding. It's almost like the DOM needs a refresh or something to trigger the padding to be shown.

```
<!-- Html table -->
<div class="cont">
        <table id="table">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Record Data</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <p><a id="showData"href="#">Show More</a></p>     
     </div> 

<!-- CSS -->
    #table { position: relative; width: 800px; height: 470px; overflow-y: scroll; padding: 10px;  }
    #showData { display: block; padding-top: 10px; }


 <!-- Event handler for Show more button -->
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {       
        $('#showData').click(function () {

            $.ajax({
                ...
                success: function (data) {                        
                    $('#table tbody').append(data.d.Html);
                },
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Returned Data**

The ajax call just returns a bunch of table rows. There are no classes or id's on any of the returned html.

example of data returned by a call

```
<tr>
<td>some returned data 1</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
<td>some returned data 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>some returned data 3</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What HTML does the AJAX call return? It may be that you're appending another element with the ID `showData`, and that's throwing off the styling in other browsers.

Comment: The ajax just returns a table row <tr><td>Some message</td></tr>. There are no classes or id's in the html returned from the ajax call. I've updated my question with the returned data.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
#showData {
    display: block;
    ...
}
```

An you forgot to close `<p>`:

```
<p><a id="showData" href="#">Show More</a></p> <!-- there! -->
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't even notice the tag was unclosed :) I've updated the example with those changes. Still same result

Comment: Can you put a up a jsfiddle? It would be better to debug.

Comment: It's a stripped down example of a page on qa :( I'm not sure how to get it to work on js fiddle with the ajax and all

Answer (score 0):

"the button loses it's bottom padding"...

Your CSS has `padding-bottom` set to `0px`. Try increasing it? Or remove it outright so that it doesn't overwrite the implied `10px` from `padding` which immediately precedes it.

```
#showData { display: block; padding: 10px; padding-bottom: 0px; }
```

Comment: Actually it should be like that because the table itself has a 10px padding around it. I should probably change that to padding-top: 10px or margin-top: 10px;